# selecting columns while importing data with DataFrames.readtable

Tags: dataframe, julia

Is there a way to select only few columns while importing the data using readtable ?
Something like pandas read_csv "usecols" method

```
movies = pd.read_csv('data/ml-100k/u.item', sep='|', names=m_col_names, usecols=range(5))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supported directly yet, in that [this ticket](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/issues/568) is still open and nothing leaps out when you skim the source.

Comment: You could read the file into a data frame and then copy only the columns desired into another data frame.

Comment: Yes thats always the workaround but my question was more to understand if there is a way to do this in julia DataFrames. Looks like there isnt any at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this issue https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/issues/568 as @DSM pointed out, current implementation of DataFrames does not support this.